# Have subsetted data, need to graph both on the same scatterplot not using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I know there are heaps of other posts asking the same question but I didn't understand any of the answers because I am 100% new to all of this and don't even understand ggplot yet. I need to plot two graphs onto one without using ggplot, but I'm not even sure if that's possible. This is my first graph:

```
 plot(AustraliaData$year4, AustraliaData$exp_mean, type = "l", col = "purple", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Australian Average", main = "Ambient Particulate Matter Pollution")
```

And this is my second graph:

```
plot(AfghanistanData$year4, AfghanistanData$exp_mean, type = "l", col = "purple", xlab = "Year", ylab = "Afghanistan Average", main = "Ambient Particulate Matter Pollution")
```

Firstly, do you think that using ggplot will make these graphs look nicer, and will it then be easier to graph them together? I want to make a comparison between the two countries.

If ggplot is easier, where can I find a good tutorial on how to do it? I have only been doing this stuff for a few weeks because my university course requires it as a prerequisite in STEM subjects.

Thanks!

```
Here is a linkto the [first bunch of data] [1]
a link to [the second bunch of data] [2]
and to [the first graph] [3]
and also [the second graph] [4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K22SX.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyXxV.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUN0a.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgwkl.png
```

Comment: "do you think that using ggplot will make these graphs look nicer" Hard to say, could you post your data or at least a picture of what the graph looks like? I love `ggplot`, so if you post your data I could give you a walkthrough of how to do it that way

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering! Where should I post my data? just add it to the post? I am adding it now, any help would be great, thanks!!

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) for specifics on how to post an R question that is easy for us to answer. Pasting in the output of calling `dput` on your data is the best way to go

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way, if you prefer to use base R, is as follows:

```
plot(AustraliaData$year4, AustraliaData$exp_mean, xlab = "Year", ylab = "Average", main = "Ambient Particulate Matter Pollution")
lines(lowess(AustraliaData$year4, AustraliaData$exp_mean), col = "purple")
points(AfghanistanData$year4, AfghanistanData$exp_mean)
lines(lowess(AfghanistanData$year4, AfghanistanData$exp_mean), col = "green")
```

Note that you may need to specify xlim= and ylim= in your call to plot() to ensure that both datasets are "in frame"

Answer (score 0):

welcome to R.
As beginning I want to recommend the Book [R for Data Science" by Hadley Wickham](http://r4ds.had.co.nz) to you. It's a great place to start and includes everything you need to know about ggplot2.
To answer your question, which by the may lacks a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6549166), try `par(mfcol = c(2,1))` - it will split your plotting window into two horiontal ones; `par(mfcol = c(1,2))` does the same but splits vertically. Last but not least return to "normal" by typing `par(mfcol = c(1,1))`.
Best wishes!